Splitting and bracketing months based on number of weeks and determine the beginning of the month
I want to define each month of the year based on the number of weeks so as to avoid the confusion due to some months having 30 or 31 days.
For example, Jan to Dec would be have weeks of the following configuration:
Jan - 4 wks
Feb - 4 wks
Mar - 5 wks
Apr - 4 wks
May - 4 wks
Jun - 5 wks
and so on...

Then based on the current datetime, I want to find the beginning of the month so I can use that as a date filter in my dataframes.
The beginning of hte month will not be the typical 1st of the Julian calendar but instead whatever date the week starts with where Sunday will be the beginning of the week.
For example the month of April 2024 will have 4 weeks (weeknumber 14 to 17). Week 14 starts on Mar 31st so the datefilter value will be 2024-03-31
Similarly, the month of May 2024 will have 5 weeks (weeknumber 18 to 21). Week 18 starts on April 28th so the datefilter value will be 2024-04-28
My code so far:
import datetime

current_weekday = datetime.datetime.now().weekday()
sunday_as_zero = (current_weekday + 1) % 7 #Setting Sunday weekday as zero
if (sunday_as_zero == 0):
    week_to_date = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
else:
week_to_date = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=sunday_as_zero)
weeknum=week_to_date.isocalendar().week
if weeknum in [13, 26, 39, 52]:
    datefilter= datetime.datetime.now() + pd.DateOffset(weeks=-5)
else:
    datefilter= datetime.datetime.now() + pd.DateOffset(weeks=-4)
datefilter=datefilter.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

The 13,26,39 and 52 are the ending week numbers for the months that have 5 weeks.
How do i get the offset to be the beginning weeknumber without having to literally define the conditions for each month?
Is there a more elegant way to do this?

... and you consider this is less confusing than months having different numbers of days?

"due to some months having 30 or 31 days" - uh, some actually also have 28 or 29. But that is just a leap year check and a lookup table, or, if you like some fancy bit jiggling, you can avoid even that.

@user19077881 This is commonly used in finance reporting. Since the Julian calendar is not evenly distributed. Is there no solution for this kind of requirement?
